# Fluid image overlapping div when width: 100%;

Tags: javascript, html, css, fluid-layout

I am trying to figure out why my div is being overlapped by other div.

the markup looks like

```
 <div  class="headerCarrousel">
    <img src="data/img/1_hero_carrousel/1.jpg" >
    <img src="data/img/1_hero_carrousel/2.jpg" >
    <img src="data/img/1_hero_carrousel/3.jpg" >
 </div>


 <div class="theStory">
    <p>aaaa</p>
 </div>
```

and my style I am using sass, that's why this code structure.

```
.headerCarrousel {
   min-width: 1024px;
}

.headerCarrousel img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}

.theStory{
    margin: 0 auto; 
    text-align: center; 
}
```

So the div "theStory" is underneath the div headerCarrousel for some reason, being overlapped. Note that I have to have the imagery as a fluid carrousel, that's why I am using width: 100%;

link to illustrate: http://marceloduende.com/tango/

Anybody has a solution for this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

To fix that I had to add my height dynamically with jquery.

```
$('.headerCarrousel')
.css('height', $('.headerCarrousel img').height());
```

Thank you all.